# cmd.exe failed with args /c "D:\D A T A\Unreal Projects\ARTutorial\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug

Tags: unreal-engine4

UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): ERROR: cmd.exe failed with args /c "D:\D A T A\Unreal Projects\ARTutorial\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):        (see C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\D+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.27\Log.txt for full exception trace)
PackagingResults: Error: cmd.exe failed with args /c "D:\D A T A\Unreal Projects\ARTutorial\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug